Rotman-Homological algebra Chapter 2 exercise 2.33
This problem is from Rotman-Homological algebra Ch-2-exer-2.33. Consider the following commutative diagram:

If the above diagram is exact, then the map $C' \to C$ is also injective and hence, the third row is also exact. I tried a few approaches but don't know how to solve this.

What did you tried?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Tried diagram chasing by assuming any $x$ that goes to 0 in the map $C' \to C$, but couldn't suceed in showing that only x =0 is solution.

Please put your attempt at a chase in the question.

You can try to show that for $x \in C'$ that is in the kernel, there is some $y \in A'$, such that $x$ is the image of $y$.

I am posting my answer here:
I named the horizontal arrows in the above diagram by $\alpha_1, \alpha_2,\alpha_3 : A' \to A; B' \to B ; C' \to C$. $\beta_1, \beta_2,\beta_3 : A \to A''; B \to B'' ; C \to C''$. and the vertical maps by $f_1, f_2, f_3: A' \to B'; A \to B ;  A'' \to B''$  and  $g_1, g_2, g_3: B' \to C'; B \to C ;  B'' \to C''$.
Let's say that $ \alpha_3(x)=0$. We claim that $x=0$ is the only possible solution. We use diagram chasing. So, there exist $a_{B'} \in B'$ s.t. $g_1(a_{B'}) = x$. Let $\alpha_2(a_{B'}) \in Im(\alpha_2) = Ker(\beta_2)$. Since, $g_2 (\alpha_2(a_{B'})) =0 \Rightarrow  \alpha_2(a_{B'}) \in Ker (g_2) = Im(f_2) $. Let $a_A$ be s.t. $f_2(a_A) = \alpha_2(a_{B'})$.
Now, $\beta_1(a_A) \in Ker(f_3) = 0$ since $f_3$ is given to be injective. So, $\beta_1(a_A) =0 \Rightarrow a_A \in Im(\alpha_1)$ and assume $\alpha{a_{A'}}=a_A$.
Notice that $\alpha_2 (a_{B'} - f_1(a_{A'}) ) =  \alpha_2 (a_{B'}) - \alpha_2 f_1 (a_{A'}) = \alpha_2 (a_{B'}) - \alpha_2 (a_{B'}) =0  $. Since, $\alpha_2$ is injective, we have that
$a_{B'} = f_1(a_{A'})$. Now, $x = g_1 (a_{B'}) = g_1 (f_1(a_{A'})) = g_1\circ f_1 (a_{A'}) =0 $.
